# Flutter Tree View Widget with Nodes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new to Flutter and therefore I don't know all of Flutter's Widgets. I would like to have a tree like in my (embarrasingly bad) sketch.

[image]

I already found out about the InteractiveViewer Class that this tree should be wrapped in, in order to view the tree entirely (it might become a pretty big tree in the end).

My problem is that I don't know how to order my nodes properly. Would you put them in Column and Row Widgets? And how should I create the lines between the nodes?

I already found the graphview package but it doesn't provide all features I want a more custom thing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/graphite

Comment: This is not really what I was looking for. I want to make the tree graph on my own.